# Can IIS customTags access items other than the attribute of the tag?

Tags: iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I want to write an IIS Rewrite rule that detects `<script>` markup containing a specific string. The normal mechanism for matching on `<script>` involves matching against the `src`. I have therefore looked at creating a custom tag, but that has proved problematic.

According to a large PDF I downloaded that purported to be a manual for IIS, customTags can be defined as follows:

```xml
<customTags>
  <tags name="My Tags">
    <tag name="item" attribute="src" />
    <tag name="element" attribute="src" />
  </tags>
</customTags>
```

Initially, I thought that perhaps having a empty attribute would allow me to access the inner text of the the script tag. However, specifying

```xml
<customTags>
  <tags name="My Tags">
    <tag name="script" attribute="" />
  </tags>
</customTags>
```

throws an error. I haven't tried setting the attribute to "innerText". Will that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the page content by using the below rule:

```
 <rule name="test" preCondition="IsHTML" stopProcessing="true">
                <match pattern="style.fontSize = &quot;(.*)&quot;;" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="style.fontSize = &quot;30px&quot;;" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

this is how the rule will look like in URL rewrite:

[image]

You no need to select any tag from the drop-down list.